# Last Horcrux of Lord Voldemort

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter

In Harry Potter and the Deathly Hollows we come to know that the last horcrux or the last part of the soul of Lord Voldemort got attached to the ONLY LIVING THING IT COULD FIND as told by Dumbledore.

My question is why did it not get attached to a non-living thing in the house, why only Harry? In previous movies we have seen the ring of Tom Riddle's mother as one horcrux and his diary too. So when the spell rebounded why did the left part of his soul get attached to Harry himself?

Comment: Other hocruxes were created by Voldemort and not accidental. Harry became hocrux accidentally when spell rebounded making a connection between two which is portrayed in many instances like wand, dreams etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Harry Potter Wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Horcrux), Harry is NOT exactly a Horcrux, but rather the fragment of soul, latching onto to Harry for survival, is a **side effect** from Horcrux-making, as Voldermort had become "unstable". One may consider this a very unique phenomenon.

> **Side effects**
>
> "Tamper with the deepest mysteries — the source of life, the essence
>   of self — only if prepared for consequences of the most extreme and
>   dangerous kind."
>
> —The first of the Fundamental Laws of Magic To create a Horcrux is to
>   divide one's soul — the "essence of self" — and it is therefore in the
>   creation of a Horcrux that one falls prey to Adalbert Waffling's first
>   Fundamental Laws of Magic, which **essentially states that tampering
>   with one's soul inevitably results in grave side effects**. Creating
>   Horcruxes is considered one of the most dreadful acts possible.

---

> **Instability**
>
> A third side effect of Horcrux creation is that the master soul itself
>   becomes unstable (even with creating just one Horcrux). The precise
>   dangers of this spiritual **destabilisation are not currently detailed
>   explicitly throughout the franchise**, however, some can be gleaned
>   from the events in the books.
>
> For example, the creation of Voldemort's sixth "Horcrux" — Harry
>   Potter — is known to be the direct result of this.[2] When Voldemort
>   was hit by the back-fired Killing Curse at Potters' home in Godric's
>   Hollow, it caused Voldemort's soul to split, with one fragment
>   remaining in him and the other displaced part immediately seeking out
>   the only other living thing in the room and latching onto it — Harry
>   Potter. However, **this parasitic fragment of Voldemort's soul that
>   attached to Harry was not actually a Horcrux, since it was not created
>   intentionally and the necessary parts of the Horcrux creation process
>   were not carried out**.[8]

Comment: As I recall, Dumbledore explicitly says in the last book that Harry was "the horcrux that Voldemort never planned to make", but JK Rowling later said in an interview that Dumbledore was incorrect; Harry was not a horcrux, hence the common confusion.